# Aarch64, ldd command retruns "Not a dynamic executable"

Tags: arm, .so, dynamic-execution

I have been trying to use run a simulator built for ubuntu from my m1 macbook. I am using parallels and a Ubuntu virtual machine. There seems to be a problem with one of the .so files.

```
$ldd libepanet.so
not a dynamic executable
```

When I run the same command from a virtual cloud machine I get a different output:

```
$ldd libepanet.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe0e191000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9baba43000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9babe99000)
```

It looks like a compatibility issue but I have no idea how to fix this, What should I do?

Comment: It's an x86-64 binary.  You'll probably have to recompile for Aarch64.

Comment: You are right. After finding the source code and building in my enviroment, it finally works.